# how to show text and image in Cell of UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview, cells

I am inheriting UITableViewController, and I want it sell something like as below output

Name                      Image

Name2                     Image2

Name3                      Image3

where these are different cells in table, how can I do implements such thing, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In your method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Insert:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
```